# Remove random item from array and push to new array

Tags: arrays, array-splice

Thank you in advance! I'm new to coding and learning how to deal with Arrays. I am trying to remove random items from an array (deck of cards), and populate a new array (called hand). The problem I always seem to have with arrays is taking the results of one and creating a new function/array/ etc..   Currently, I am outputting 2 separate arrays and I can't seem to push them into one.

```
let deck = ["dA","dQ","dK","dJ","d10","d09","d08",
"d07","d06","d05","d04","d03","d02","hA","hQ","hK",
"hJ","h10","h09","h08","h07","h06","h05","h04","h03"];


var hand = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length),1);
    console.log(hand)
var hand = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length),1);
console.log(hand);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, just you need to push the value returned from `splice` method rather than directly assigning it.
By this way every time a new value that gets deleted and will be added to the new array called `hand`. Hope this helps. :-)

```js
let deck = ["dA","dQ","dK","dJ","d10","d09","d08",
        "d07","d06","d05","d04","d03","d02","hA","hQ","hK",
        "hJ","h10","h09","h08","h07","h06","h05","h04","h03"];

var hand = [];

const getSelectedCard = () => deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length),1)

let selectedCard = getSelectedCard();
hand.push(...selectedCard) //or hand.push(selectedCard[0])
console.log(hand);

selectedCard = getSelectedCard();
hand.push(...selectedCard)
console.log(hand);
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :-). And it's my pleasure to help. Happy coding :-)
In fact this solution can be even more simplified by creating multiple methods and all. But I didn't want to confuse by providing all that stuff. Let me know if I can help in anyway

Comment: I appreciate you keeping it simple.  I had to do a little reading on the arrow function to fully understand the arrow function use. Thanks again.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc) for better understanding of arrow functions for beginners.

Comment: That was very helpful. Simply but was able to explain it thoroughly.